# Enable/Disable buttons while thread is working

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, button

I have a button that starts two threads

```
private void CrawdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrawdBtn.Enabled = false;
    t = new Thread(AddLinksToList);
    b = new Thread(EnqueueFromList);
    t.Start();
    b.Start();            
}
```

and there are another buttons to pause, Resume, Stop those threads
My question is how can I disable (pause, Resume, Stop) buttons while the threads are working and re enable Crawl after the threads finished

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do using `async/await`, are you opposed to doing it that way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266149/pause-and-resume-a-thread-from-another-thread-in-c-sharp) carefully.

Comment: The `Thread` class does not have an event `Completed` or `Finished` or `Exited`, so you must include checking code inside both methods `AddLinksToList` and `EnqueueFromList`. It would be much easier and cleaner if you used `Task`s instead of threads.

Comment: In fact I have to use thread because I don't have a lot of information about tasks and there is no time to learn tasks from zero

Comment: Then the GSerg's link is your friend for now.

Comment: Do you really use the methods [`Thread.Suspend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.suspend) and [`Thread.Resume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.resume)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I use them to pause and resume threads

Comment: Sincerely, this stuff is obsolete. It may be time to learn about newer techniques. The time will be well spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could start a `Thread` and have a way to await its completion:

```
public static Thread CreateAwaitableThread(Action action, out Task threadCompletion)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    threadCompletion = tcs.Task;
    return new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
    });
}
```

This method returns the newly created `Thread`, and also a `Task` that will be completed when the `Thread` is completed. You could use it like this:

```
private async void CrawdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrawdBtn.Enabled = false;
    Thread t1 = CreateAwaitableThread(AddLinksToList, out var t1c);
    Thread t2 = CreateAwaitableThread(EnqueueFromList, out var t2c);
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    await Task.WhenAll(t1c, t2c);
    CrawdBtn.Enabled = true;
}
```

In case of an exception the error will not be propagated through the `Task`. It is assumed that the delegates already include error handling logic. If not, an unhandled exception will occur as usual.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can make a thread to check the ThreadState of thread t and thread b

```
private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
    t = new Thread(AddLinksToList);
    b = new Thread(EnqueueFromList);


    t.Start();
    b.Start();
    if (threadchecker == null)//this if determines Whether it's the first time or not
    {
        threadchecker = new Thread(() => ChekingStateOfThreads());
        threadchecker.IsBackground = true;
        threadchecker.Start();
    }
}
```

Since the thread wants to check the ThreadState of those threads it should always run.
and This is **ChekingStateOfThreads**

```
private void ChekingStateOfThreads()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
   
        if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                btnpause.Enabled = btnstart.Enabled = false;
                btnresume.Enabled = btnstop.Enabled = true;
            }));
        }
        else if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                btnstart.Enabled = btnresume.Enabled = false;
                btnpause.Enabled = btnstop.Enabled = true;
            }));
        }
        else if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Aborted)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                btnstart.Enabled = true;
                btnpause.Enabled = btnresume.Enabled = btnstop.Enabled = false;
            }));
        }
        else if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                btnpause.Enabled = btnstart.Enabled = false;
                btnresume.Enabled = btnstop.Enabled = true;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

The concept of function is pretty simple. Each 1 second the thread is check the state of thread t.

See [Why use Invoke on Controls in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915076/why-use-invoke-on-controls-in-net) to figure out why should we use INVOKE.

To abort the threadchecker just use the Form_closing Event

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    threadchecker.Abort();
}
```